# Conditional "blind" splitting of data in R

Tags: r

I have a tricky (at least it appears to me to be tricky...) problem with conditional splitting of my data:

My data contain information on the sales a bunch of companies in different years. The companies can be identified by a distinct number, found in the variable "UNR". I am particularly interested in the sales-data of the companies, which can be found in the variable "urs_5ef16u1"; "urs_5ef16u2" gives the corresponding year where the sales-data were measured. All data for all companies and all measured years come in one dataframe:

```
> str(daten.ready)
'data.frame':   2570 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ UNR           : num  2578 3769 3769 3769 3769 ...
 $ urs_jahr      : num  2006 2013 2004 2008 2012 ...
 $ urs_1ef17     : num  2005 1995 1995 1995 1995 ...
 $ urs_1ef19     : num  1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ urs_1ef20     : num  55300 45100 50100 45100 45100 47500 47500 47500 47200 52200 ...
 $ urs_1ef25     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ urs_1ef26     : num  1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 1 1 ...
 $ urs_1ef30u4   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ urs_5ef15u1   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ urs_5ef16u1   : num  34 122 323 244 194 349 146 142 149 59 ...
 $ urs_5ef16u2   : num  2004 2011 2002 2006 2010 ...
 $ urs_5ef18u1   : num  1 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ urs_5ef18u2   : num  2004 2011 2002 2006 2010 ...
 $ urs_5ef20u1   : num  1012001 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ urs_5ef20u2   : num  NA NA NA NA 1011996 ...
 $ urs_5ef21u1   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ urs_5ef21u2   : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ urs_5ef30u1   : num  34 122 NA NA 194 349 146 142 149 59 ...
 $ urs_5ef30u2   : num  2004 2011 NA NA 2010 ...
 $ urs_teilnahme : num  1111110 1111111 1111111 1111111 1111111 ...
 $ urs_teilnak   : num  1111110 2222222 2222222 2222222 2222222 ...
 $ urs_teilnak01b: num  0 1111111 1111111 1111111 1111111 ...
 $ u_ums_akt     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I need to calculate compound annual growth rates for each company with the following formula:

*CAGR = (A(t_max)/A(t_min))^ (1/n)) – 1 * 100% 
with A(t_min) = sales at time t_min; A(t_max) = sales at time t_max; n = t_max-t_min.*

Thus, I need to first split the dataframe in subsets that contain only information for one company, second extract for each company the minimum and maximum values given for t and then find out the corresponding value of the sales-variable. The first step works fine with `tapply()` or `split()`, but as soon as I come to the next step I get stuck - mainly because of the following problem: **My data underly pretty strict secrecy requirements, so that I wont be able to actually "see" the rawdata, but have to work "blindly". I just got a dummy-datafile (shown above) to create my R-code, send it to the data-owner who will then run the code and return the results. Thus I can't work with discrete values of variables but have to use vectors with indices etc..**

I tried the following way, using `split()`:

```
> splitted <- split(daten.ready, daten.ready[["UNR"]]) 
> # split dataframe in subsets, one for each company
```

For a "test-company", e.g. the one with the UNR "3769" the next step would be easy:

```
> t_min_ind_3769 <- which.min(splitted$"3769"$urs_5ef16u2)
> t_max_ind_3769 <- which.max(splitted$"3769"$urs_5ef16u2)
> t_min_3769 <- min(splitted$"3769"$urs_5ef16u2)
> t_max_3769 <- max(splitted$"3769"$urs_5ef16u2)
> cagr_3769 <- (((splitted$"3769"[(t_max_ind_3769),10]/splitted$"3769"[(t_min_ind_3769),10]) ^ (1/(t_max_3769-t_min_3769)))-1)
> cagr_3769
[1] -0.1025351
```

How can I now "automatize" this for every company without knowing the discrete UNR? I created a vector with the numbers of the split-subsets to access them by index and then use an iteration:

```
> unique_rownr <- which(!duplicated(daten.ready[["UNR"]])) 
> # create a vector with rownumbers containing unique UNR
> unique_unr <- daten.ready[unique_rownr,1] 
> # create a vector with unique UNR
```

For my test-company it would look like this:

```
> t_min_ind_3769 <- which.min(splitted[[unique_rownr[2]]][["urs_5ef16u2"]])
> t_max_ind_3769 <- which.max(splitted[[unique_rownr[2]]][["urs_5ef16u2"]]) 
> t_min_3769 <- min(splitted[[unique_rownr[2]]][["urs_5ef16u2"]])
> t_max_3769 <- max(splitted[[unique_rownr[2]]][["urs_5ef16u2"]])
> cagr_3769 <- (((splitted[[unique_rownr[2]]][(t_max_ind_3769),10]/splitted[[unique_rownr[2]]][(t_min_ind_3769),10]) ^ (1/(t_max_3769-t_min_3769)))-1)
> cagr_3769
[1] -0.1025351
```

It works fine until here. But I get stuck trying to create a loop:

```
> for (i in unique_rownr) 
+ { t_min_ind_i <- which.min(splitted$unique_rownr[i][["urs_5ef16u2"]]);
+ t_max_ind_i <- which.max(splitted[[unique_rownr[i]]][["urs_5ef16u2"]]); 
+ t_min_i <- min(splitted[[unique_rownr[i]]][["urs_5ef16u2"]]);
+ t_max_i <- max(splitted[[unique_rownr[i]]][["urs_5ef16u2"]]);
+ cagr_i <- (((splitted[[unique_rownr[i]]][(t_max_ind_i),10]/splitted[[unique_rownr[i]]][(t_min_ind_i),10]) ^ (1/(t_max_i-t_min_i)))-1)
+ }
Error in splitted[[unique_rownr[i]]] : subscript out of bounds
```

For me it looks like my trick with the vector to access the subsets doesn't work... Or is the mistake somewhere else? Does anyone have a suggestion if I am on the right way here - or if there is an easier way to solve my problem, e.g. with `tapply()` or `subset()` or any another function? I'd also rather avoid the iteration as the original dataframe will be quite huge...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the trick here is just to turn your code from the test company into a function, and then loop that through the list. Something like

```
compound <- function(x) {
    t_min_ind_3769 <- which.min(x$urs_5ef16u2)
    t_max_ind_3769 <- which.max(x$urs_5ef16u2)
    t_min_3769 <- min(x$urs_5ef16u2)
    t_max_3769 <- max(x$urs_5ef16u2)

    (((x[(t_max_ind_3769),10]/x[(t_min_ind_3769),10]) ^(1/(t_max_3769-t_min_3769)))-1)
}
```

And then loop that through the list with

```
sapply(splitted, compound)
```

Answer (score 0):

let me show you some `dplyr`, i recommend reading more about it.

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
```

here you will `group_by` your grouping variable and then use `summarise` to apply some function. i will use `mean` but this could be defined by you as in Daniels answer.

```
means <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Sepal.Length))
```